# Fancybox (V. 3.x) : How to place Counter directly above the image and not at the top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I need to place the Image Counter directly above the image and not at the top of the page (this is the default behavior). Because of users different screen height the position could not be set with CSS top:20px or something like this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your head tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and use classes for all your elements and use the `background-position: 32% 30%;/*use values as per your needs*/` property in css to place your elements in your desired x,y location